# How to get a list item <li> using a plain text field every time I hit enter

Tags: templating, field, twigextension

I'm trying to get a list from a simple plain text field which will accept line breaks. I need to find a way to wrap an li tag around the content on that line. So everytime I hit enter, it wraps `<li>Whatever is on that line</li>`

So going from this:

[image]

Into this:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to [split](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/split.html) on the line breaks, then loop through the resulting array...

```html
{% for ingredient in listOfIngredients|trim|split('\n') %}
    <li>{{ ingredient }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```